# Updating documents with the help of cas in couchbase 2.0 server using PHP API

Tags: php, couchbase

I am trying to update a document in Couchbase 2.0 server using PHP API (php-ext-couchbase).
http://www.couchbase.com/docs/couchbase-sdk-php-1.1/api-reference-summary.html

The document is similar to facebook POSTS with comments and likes associated with it.

To be more specific.

-Load the doc.

-Modify it

-Store the modified doc if it has not been accessed by any other person.

Basic operations that would be required to accomplish this will be

```
# Get a document by key
doc = get(key)
# Modify a document when no one has modified it since my last read
casVersion = doc.getCas()
cas(key, casVersion, changedDoc)
```

I just want to know how i can accomplish this in PHP.
especially how to get the casVersion or the revision_id of the document and then further carry out the update process so that changes made by simultaneous updates on same document are not lost.

Answer (score 0):

No worries I found it,

The code is

```
    $bucket='yourbucketname';
    $cb=new Couchbase("127.0.0.1:8091","root","password",$bucket);

    $old_doc=null;

    $cb->getDelayed($obj_id, true,
    function($cb, $data) use (&$old_doc) { $old_doc = $data; });

    $casKey=$old_doc['cas'];
```

Use getDelayed method, and callback function to get the  array  having (key,value,caskey)

I hope the couchbase documentation would be more clear in future with usages examples.

Comment: so by this method you can retrieve the document with its cas key.

Comment: $obj_id is the key for the document,